# Vertical menu won't show my submenu on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress

I am creating a [vertical menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28185953/javascript-for-dropdown-menu-wp-nav-menu-not-working) that opens and closes the submenu (with js).
I do this with a WordPress menu so the setup is as following:

```
<div id="menu">
    <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'webshop-menu') ); ?>
</div>
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $("#menu > div > ul > li > a").click(function (e) { // binding onclick
        if ($(this).parent().hasClass('selected')) {
            $("#menu .selected ul").slideUp(100); // hiding popups
            $("#menu .selected").removeClass("selected");
        } else {
            $("#menu .selected ul").slideUp(100); // hiding popups
            $("#menu .selected").removeClass("selected");

            if ($(this).next(".sub-menu").length) {
                $(this).parent().addClass("selected"); // display popup
                $(this).next(".sub-menu").children().slideDown(200);
            }
        }
        e.stopPropagation();
    }); 

    $("html").click(function () { // binding onclick to body
        $("#menu .selected ul").slideUp(100); // hiding popups
        $("#menu .selected").removeClass("selected");
    }); 

});
</script>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
#menu {
    float: right;
    position: relative;
    top: 25px;
}
#menu > div > ul > li {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0 1em;
}
#menu > div > ul > li.menu-item-has-children a:after {
    content: " \f107";
    font-family: FontAwesome;
}
#menu li a {
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
}
#menu li a:hover {
    color: #000;
}
#menu > div > ul > li > ul {
    display: none;
}
#menu > div > ul > li > ul.selected {
    display: inline;
}
```

I do see the menu and I can't find any errors or warnings.
What am I missing?

I came across the following thought:

> Can it be because the link has a page attached to it? If the page has no page then it might work because there is no destination....!

M.

Comment: You need to show the parsed HTML/menu, showing php isn't of any use for this question as it gives us nothing to work with. Impossible to debug to contents of `wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'webshop-menu') );` if we don't know what the output is.

Comment: I see your point. But now that it works..... Thnx for the comment though